# How to add popovers for every cell in view collection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I've writing an app (kind of game) with words. So, I have WordsVC with `CollectionView` (where every cell is a word). And when word (cell) is long tapped, I want to show popover with translation beside the cell.

But I can't add segue to cell (Xcode give me an error, kind of "can't compile"). 
So, I'm segueing from `CollectionView` to TraslationVC(popover). And that is problem, because popover pops up in view collection's left top corner (I need beside tapped cell).

I couldn't fine answer, by searching. What can I do to achieve it?

Here's some code:

Preparation for segue in WordsVC:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // for another segue
    if segue.identifier == "fromWordsToWin" {
        if let wvc = sender as? WordsViewController {
            if let winVC = segue.destination as? WinningViewController {
                winVC.completedLevel = wvc.currentLevel
                winVC.levelsCount = wvc.dataSource.count()
                winVC.resultTime = wvc.result
            }
        }
    }
    // here
    if segue.identifier == "translationSegue" {
        if let cell = sender as? WordCell {
            if let tvc = segue.destination as? TranslationViewController {
                tvc.text = cell.myLabel.text ?? "empty cell"
                if let ppc = tvc.popoverPresentationController {
                    ppc.delegate = self
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting not modal style in WordsVC:

```
 func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

Segueing (from WordsVC):

```
@objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("long tap happend")
    if let cell = sender.view as? WordCell {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "translationSegue", sender: cell)
    }
```

And setting size of popover in TranslatingVC:

```
 override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        if textView != nil && presentingViewController != nil {
            return textView.sizeThatFits(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size)
        } else {
            return super.preferredContentSize
        }
    }
    set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue}
}
```

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: by the way, i'm a new in swift. And app will be working on iPhones basically (not iPads)

Comment: Can you try using sourceView property of your popoverViewController like popoverVc.sourceView = cell.myLabel and check ?

Comment: @Ashish, my popover VC is "class TranslationViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate". So i couldn't find .sourceView property.

Comment: @Ashish so, i misunderstood you. Try to find UIVC.sourceView, but have to use popoverVC.sourceView. And yes. that works! Thank you. Actually popover not at exactly place i need (it overlaps pressed word, i need it to be beside). trying to fix it

Comment: You can use another property on it like it will have anchor direction where you set .left, .right,.top and .bottom. maybe its arrowDirection so pooverVC.arrowDirection not sure on property name but you get the idea right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've been advised to use popoverViewController.sourceView. So, it works well! I also added some setting of exact location of my popover. My code in prepareForSegue below (last 2 lines in code):

```
 if segue.identifier == "translationSegue" {
        if let cell = sender as? WordCell {
            if let tvc = segue.destination as? TranslationViewController {
                tvc.text = cell.myLabel.text ?? "empty cell"
                if let ppc = tvc.popoverPresentationController {
                    ppc.delegate = self
                    ppc.sourceView = cell
                    ppc.sourceRect = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.minX + cell.bounds.width / 5, y: cell.bounds.minY, width: 50, height: 50 )
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

[screenshot, how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IykS4.png)